# Parsing Name Field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to separate a name field into the appropriate fields. The name field is not consistently the same. It can show up as **Doe III,John w** or **Doe,John,** or **Doe III,John,** or **Doe,John W** or it may be lacking the suffix and or middle initial. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT (
        CASE LEN(REPLACE(FirstName, ' ', ''))
            WHEN LEN(FirstName + ' ') - 1
                THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(FirstName, ' ', '.'), 2)
            ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE(FirstName, ' ', '.'), 3)
            END
        ) AS LastName
    ,(
        CASE LEN(REPLACE(FirstName, ' ', ''))
            WHEN LEN(FirstName + ',') - 1
                THEN NULL
            ELSE PARSENAME(REPLACE(FirstName, ' ', '.'), 2)
            END
        ) AS Suffix
    ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(FirstName, ' ', '.'), 1) AS FirstName
FROM Trusts.dbo.tblMember
```

I need the name regardless of the format, as stated above, to parse into the appropriate fields of LastName,Suffix,FirstName,MiddleInitial, regardless of whether it has a suffix or a middle initial

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good sql question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/5234334) and mention your database, expected result, sample data

Comment: I have tried the following:
 ( case LEN(REPLACE(FirstName,' ','')) when LEN(FirstName + ' ') - 1 then PARSENAME(REPLACE(FirstName,' ','.'), 2) else PARSENAME(REPLACE(FirstName,' ','.'), 3) end ) as LastName,
 ( case LEN(REPLACE(FirstName,' ','')) when LEN(FirstName + ',') - 1 then null else PARSENAME(REPLACE(FirstName,' ','.'), 2) end ) as Suffix,
 PARSENAME(REPLACE(FirstName,' ','.'), 1) as FirstName
from Trusts.dbo.tblMember

Comment: Then question is very vague without sample data which handles all the cases and your expected output based on that. Use rextester.com to create table and insert sample rows in SQL server and tell us your expected output based on that.

Comment: I am confused I have clearly stated the output I need.  I need the name regardless of the format, as stated above, to parse into the appropriate fields of LastName,Suffix,FirstName,MiddleInitial, regardless of whether it has a suffix or a middle initial

Comment: You did clearly state the requirements but you didn't provide any detail about the data or the tables involved. Without this nobody can really help much. But I wouldn't bother in this case. It sounds like your data is all over the place. Names are one of the most difficult things to automate because there are so many possibilities. There is no good way to automate this as every approach will spit out bad data in some cases.

Comment: Exactly. And that's why I asked to give sample data for **all possible cases** ,before we can attempt to answer. And the corresponding expected output.

Comment: The best I can provide at this time is names can appear as the following: Doe III,John w or Doe,John, or Doe III,John, or Doe,John W that is every example of the data.  I am trying to correct data we are receiving to go into the tables in the proper way for utilization.  Sorry its my first time using this site.

Comment: If you are on SQL Server 2012 or higher and want to go for a deep dive you could investigate Data Quality Services (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877925(v=sql.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If the given 4 names are the only type of cases, then you can use something like below.

Note: I used a CTE table `tbl2` to separate `comma_pos`,`first_space`,`second_space` for better understanding in the main query. You can replace these value in main query with their corresponding function in CTE, to make the main query faster. I mean replace `comma_pos` in main query with `charindex(',',name)` an so on.

Also I am assuming that there are no leading/trailing or extra whitespaces or any junk character in `name` column. If you have, then sanitize your data first before proceeding.

[Rexter Sample](http://rextester.com/DQPOE44702)

```
with tbl2 as (
select tbl.*,
    charindex(',',name) as comma_pos,
    charindex(' ',name,1) first_space,
    charindex(' ',name,charindex(' ',name,1)+1) second_space
from tbl)

select tbl2.name

,case when second_space <> 0
        then substring(name,comma_pos+1,second_space-comma_pos-1)
      when first_space > comma_pos
        then substring(name,comma_pos+1,first_space-comma_pos-1)
      else substring(name,comma_pos+1,len(name)-comma_pos)
end as first_name

,case when second_space <> 0
        then substring(name,second_space+1,len(name)-second_space)
      when first_space > comma_pos
        then substring(name,first_space+1,len(name)-first_space)
      end as middle_name
,case when first_space=0 or first_space>comma_pos
    then substring(name,1,comma_pos-1)
    else substring(name,1,first_space-1) 
end as last_name
,case when first_space=0 or first_space>comma_pos
    then null
    else substring(name,first_space,comma_pos-first_space) 
end as suffix

from  tbl2;
```